# HTML overlay not covering flexbox layout

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML/CSS pure layout and I'm using flexbox. I am developing a simple hamburger overlay menu sort of thing, but the overlay isn't fully covering the entire site -- there is no higher z-index present.

If I change the opacity to 0, the entire page goes white.

#### Desired Output:

Div that covers the entire page

#### Current Output (See Below):

#### HTML

```
<body data-theme="light" class="overlay">
...
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

#### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make the HTML `body` an overlay because it is the main container for the whole page, so it contains the elements you are trying to overlay.

Instead you can create a separate div for the overlay. This shouldn't have any content (unless you want content in your overlay of course). Then you can add your existing overlay class to it:

```css
.overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
h1, p { color: red;}
```

```html
<body data-theme="light">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I was wrapping everything inside the overlay div after I ripped off the main body tag, but this is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you may add

```
.FlexContainer{position: relative;}
```

Next a few changes for the Overlay:

```
.FlexContainer .Overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(013, 130, 230, 0.5);
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```